# Delete Vote or Flag?

Tags: discussion, flags, vote-to-delete

I've just come across this question:

[image]

With these types of questions, is it best to just let delete votes take care of it, or should it be flagged for more immediate results?

I just delete-voted for now

Comment: delete (2) and counting...

Comment: ...aaaand gone.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If there's really no hope of redemption for the question, then casting a delete vote is fine.  Getting rid of the questions that don't show effort is ideal.

Otherwise, if there was a *sliver* of hope that this question could be turned around, if there were stellar answers on it already, or there were well-accepted answers, I'd revert the edit immediately and notify a moderator that this is turning into an edit war.

It's especially important in regards to the answers - if the answers are good, but the question is being actively vandalized, that's a problem.  You'd want to let a diamond moderator know about that.  Otherwise, if there's really no redeeming factor to it, deleting it is fine.